# how to pass the dynamic value in functiion in python

Tags: python-3.x, function

I can pass n number of value(parameter) , but if I don't know the numbers of value(parameter) in function so, how could I ?

if You could explain me with code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *args and/or **kwargs. It will be great to do some reading on it [here](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/). It will explain it better than me.

But basically if you have a function

```
def print_my_arguments(*args):
  for item in args:
    print(item)

print_my_arguments("hi", "hello", "whatsup")

> "hi"
> "hello"
> "whatsup"
```

You might find kwargs is more suitable for your use case, in which case you can find out more in the link i provided above!